# starting Android app on multiple emulators simultaneously

Tags: android, testing, emulation

As we all know, Android resolution is rather fragmented.

I (like many others) don't have all the screen resolution, or OS versions to test my app on.

Emulators give a solution to the resolution and OS problem, but it is getting rather tedious and annoying to run my app on each emulator (even if they are already running) just to see one layout.

So, my question is; is there any way to run my app on EACH emulator I have selected, not doing them individually?

For now, I am using a solution called Manymo, which allows me to launch emulators faster, but my ideal solution would be to start 1 app, and have a setting to be able to launch it simultaneously on several emulators.

I am surprised to see after many searches, that although people ask about running multiple, I can't seem to find anyone who would like to launch an app in multiple instances simultaneously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've got your emulators running, I believe in the *Run Configurations* control, you can select *Launch on all compatible devices/AVD's* and then select *Active AVD's* from the dropdown. I believe this should launch your app on all emulators you have running. Could be quite taxing on your system, though, unless you're swimming in RAM.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. I have 16gb, so I think should be ok

Comment: Do you know a way to do it in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is exactly, what you want but you dont even need to start an emulator to check how a layout will look like.
the ADT plugin in Eclipse allows you to check how a layout will look on different versions and devices without having to start each emulator every time.

Graphical Layout , allows you to select a device, the orientation and android OS version.

Comment: Just remember that for anything but simple layouts, the layout preview there is all but useless. Custom classes, complex listviews, etc make it have a fit.